# android show hide dialogfragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-bottomsheetdialog, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I have custom `DialogFragment` which called from another fragment:

```
final CustomCalendarDialogFragment newFragment = new CustomCalendarDialogFragment("CHOOSE_WEEK");
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (newFragment.isAdded()){
            newFragment.getDialog().show();
        } else {
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "CUSTOM_CALENDAR");
        }
    }
});
```

In `CustomCalendarDialogFragment`  when pressed "OK":

```
getDialog().hide();
```

After pressed on "OK" `DialogFragment` is hide, but when I unlock screen `DialogFragment` is displayed.
How to eliminate it?

Comment: I think your applications activity is restarted after screen unlock. So you must save the current state of your application when activity is stopped and restore it manually after screen unlock.

Comment: Try using getDialog().dismiss();

Answer (score 0):

You can track the state of showing/hiding the dialog in the `tag` attribute of the fragment view.

Initially set it as true (equivalent to shown) in `onCreateView()`

```
@Nullable
@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, container, false);
    view.setTag(true);
    return view
}
```

And whenever you show/hide it set it to true/false:

```
final CustomCalendarDialogFragment newFragment = new CustomCalendarDialogFragment("CHOOSE_WEEK");
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (newFragment.isAdded()){
            newFragment.getDialog().show();
        } else {
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "CUSTOM_CALENDAR");
            newFragment.requireView().setTag(true);
        }
    }
});
```

And set `newFragment.requireView().setTag(false);` when you call `getDialog().hide();`

And when the app goes to the background, check that tag on `onResume()` to see if you want to keep the dialog shown or hide it:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Object tag = newFragment.requireView().getTag();
    if (tag instanceof Boolean){
        if ((!(boolean)tag))
            newFragment.getDialog().hide();
    }

}
```